# How to display phpinfo() within Laravel for debugging PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

What is the easiest way to display PHP configuration using

```php
phpinfo();
```

in a Laravel application, to debug local PHP configuration in a development environment?

**Background:**

I need to find out on my Mac, where brew placed the `php.ini` file which is read.

Comment: Anything not working if you simply call `phpinfo`?

Answer (score 25):

For Laravel ..routes\web.php

add:

```
    Route::get('phpmyinfo', function () {
    phpinfo(); 
})->name('phpmyinfo');
```

Then in your URL type yourdomain.com/phpmyinfo

Comment: For me this is the most quick and clean solution.

Answer (score 5):

Go to Laravel folder

```
/public
```

open

```
index.php
```

Look for the comment block

```
|---------------------
| Run The Application
|---------------------
```

**Under** that block just place

```
phpinfo();
```

Then start Laravel application with

```
php artisan serve
```

And open the application in browser.
Don't forget to remove the line.

**Please note:**

This is only for local debugging purposes, as you reveal confidential information about PHP config.

Comment: why would you do this ... `php --ini`

Comment: @lagbox I appreciate your feedback, this is a very good alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Using `phpinfo();` like that is usually only needed if you are trying to figure out the configuration the webserver is using for PHP. From the CLI this is not needed.

```
php --ini
```

Comment: Refined it `php -ini | grep "php.ini"`

Comment: `php --ini` is different than `php -i` btw (which is what you are calling with `php -ini`, since it is only reading the 'i') ... one just returns the ini configuration the other is all the info (more similar to what `phpinfo` is showing)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a separate Info file for debugging purpose only

Go to project root folder

`cd public`

`nano phpinfo.php`

```php
<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

?>
```

**Run Laravel :**
`php artisan serve`

**VIEW YOUR PHPINFO PAGE**

To view your php info page, open a browser and go to the URL
http://localhost/phpinfo.php

***Please note:***

This is only for local debugging purposes, You expose everything in this file , Remove this before putting code in production

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tinker`

```
php artisan tinker

phpinfo();
```

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.